# Align 2 div without size

Tags: css, width, alignment, inline, percentage

Is possible auto align in line 2 div **without size**?
The goal is to get something like the image attached.

I can't set percentages (80% and 20%) because the content is dynamic. I can't use tables. Any idea?
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hKRyG/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.navbar {
    width: 500px;
    background: #ccc;    
    display:table;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb {    
    float:left;    
}

.navbar .breadcrumb ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

.navbar .navbutton {
    float: right;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">

<div class="breadcrumb">
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
<li>-></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
<li>-></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
<li>-></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
</ul>
</div>
    
<div class="navbutton">
    <input type="button" value="BUTTON" />
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go! To align without defined size you must use table display properties

```
.navbar {
    width: 500px;
    background: #ccc;    
    display:table;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;

}

.navbar ul{
    display: table-cell;
}

.navbutton {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Did you inadvertently delete the `display: inline;` from the `.navbar .breadcrumb li` style definition?

Comment: oops i inadvertently deleted it :P Sorry! I am editing the answer right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.navbar {
width: 500px;
background: #ccc;    
display:table;
float: left;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb {    
float:left;    
}

.navbar .breadcrumb ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

.navbar .navbutton {
 float: right;    
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="navbar">

 <div class="breadcrumb">
 <ul>
 <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
 <li>-></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
 <li>-></li>
 <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
 <li>-></li>
 <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
 </div>



 </div>
 <div class="navbutton">
<input type="button" value="BUTTON" />
 </div>
 <body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move the button to the top of the markup and give it a `float: right;`, then add `overflow: hidden;` to the `<div class="breadcrumb">` the button should be flush right and the breadcrumb will take up whatever room remains on the left.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKRyG/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbutton">
        <input type="button" value="BUTTON" />
    </div>
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
            <li>-></li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
            <li>-></li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
            <li>-></li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    width: 500px;
    background: #ccc; 
}

.navbar .navbutton {
    float: right;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb { 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar .breadcrumb li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}​
```

Comment: In that case, I would go with [marctrem's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13841709/1888292), but keep the `display: inline;` on the `.navbar .breadcrumb li` styling. This is his code with just that change: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKRyG/2/).

Comment: Yes, the example of @marctrem is Ok. Thank you.